# How to access MySQL server via AWS Lambda C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda

Anyone able to use AWS Lambda with C# .NET Core to access MySQL database in AWS RDS?

I tried "**Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql**" v1.1 from nuget and tested out working in Console Application (.NET Core) before shifting it into AWS Lambda.

I am running Visual Studio Professional Update 3 and .NET Core 1.0.1 - VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2.

My test code is simple...just test to open MySQL database in AWS RDS, things worked out fine in Console Application, but showing error "**Operation is not supported on this platform.**" when moved to Lambda.

Any ideas how to resolve this or any working sample on Lambda C# to access RDS MySQL database?

Below is my test code,

**Function.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Amazon.Lambda.Core;
using Amazon.Lambda.Serialization;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

// Assembly attribute to enable the Lambda function's JSON input to be converted into a .NET class.
[assembly: LambdaSerializerAttribute(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer))]

namespace AWSLambda1
{
    public class Function
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// A simple function that takes a string and does a ToUpper
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="input"></param>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string FunctionHandler(ILambdaContext context)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Lambda starting");
            using (var mySQLcontext = new MyContext())
            {
                // Create database
                mySQLcontext.Database.EnsureCreated();
            }
            return "Lambda stopped";
        }
    }

    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        //public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
            => optionsBuilder
                .UseMySql(@"Server=your_dbsvr_host;database=testDB;uid=admin;pwd=password123");
    }
}
```

**project.json**

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.0"
    },
    "Amazon.Lambda.Core": "1.0.0*",
    "Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json": "1.0.1",
    "Amazon.Lambda.Tools": {
      "type": "build",
      "version": "1.3.0-preview1"
    },
    "Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql": "1.1.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Amazon.Lambda.Tools" : "1.3.0-preview1"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

**Lambda Error Response**

```
{
  "errorType": "PlatformNotSupportedException",
  "errorMessage": "Operation is not supported on this platform.",
  "stackTrace": [
    "at System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform.get_Windows()",
    "at MySql.Data.Serialization.ConnectionSettings..ctor(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder csb)",
    "at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)",
    "at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.MySqlRelationalConnection.get_DbConnection()",
    "at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.MySqlRelationalConnection.Open()",
    "at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.MySqlDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean retryOnNotExists)",
    "at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabaseCreator.EnsureCreated()",
    "at AWSLambda1.Function.FunctionHandler(ILambdaContext context)",
    "at lambda_method(Closure , Stream , Stream , ContextInfo )"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are missing a "runtime" specification in your project.json file. This is not specific to only .Net Core running in Lambda, but necessary in all .Net Core apps.

The syntax looks like:

```
    "runtimes": {
        "win10-x64": {}
    }
```

Also, here is Microsoft's documentation on runtime identifiers: [.Net Core RID's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/rid-catalog), which has a list of valid runtimes. The "win10-x64" runtime is fine for Lambda

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're running into [this bug](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/issues/170) in the underlying [MySqlConnector](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector) libary, which was fixed in January 2017.

Updating the `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` package to 1.1.1 will bring in a newer version of MySqlConnector and fix this bug.